# Headless Chrome crashes when converting large HTML file to PDF on Heroku server

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I’m trying to use Chrome (version 78.0.3904.108) from the [Heroku buildpack for Google Chrome](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/) in headless mode to create a PDF of an HTML file on a Heroku “hobby” dyno.

It works fine for small files. But when I try to convert a 428 KiB HTML file it crashes after a few seconds. The files all contain a lot of images that are also referenced through `file://` URLs. I used the same Chrome version to convert the large file on my computer, and it worked without a problem.

The invocation goes as follows:

```
~ $ $HOME/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome \
>     --headless \
>     --no-sandbox \
>     --disable-gpu \
>     --print-to-pdf="/tmp/test.pdf" \
>     file:///tmp/large-file.html
[1127/175233.676324:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[1127/175233.694403:ERROR:print_render_frame_helper.cc(1785)] Printing failed.
[1127/175233.695067:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(562)] Print to PDF failed
```

The `ulimit` is `unlimited`, there is space left in /tmp, and /tmp is writeable.

Does Chrome start a lot of processes or threads so that it exceeds [these limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#processes-threads)? Or is `ulimit` uninformative for some container-related reason? Or what else could be the culprit?

Update: It works with a standard-2x dyno but not with standard-1x and below. So whatever the limitation is, it must be one that is different between those two dyno types.

Comment: I have the same issue. Im using chromium for video conferencing. after some time, my browser crashes and print these messages in the console:
ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(249)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.R1xKvc failed: Too many open files (24)